# JSON Data to View Via C# Razor

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just learned that you can pass raw json data to the view via c# razor. Something like:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeData))
```

I was wondering about the pros and cons of sending data to the view this way compared to retrieving the data through a web service call.

So far all I know is that the data I pass to the view must be displayed inline on the web page. So I guess the big things I would like to know overall is:

1) How safe is this as a method of retrieving data for an app?

2) Is there anything I can do if I wanted to pass possibly sensitive information to the view this way (like encrypt the data on the server and decrypt on the view)

3) When in general is the best time to do something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.Raw` is a helper method which simply renders some raw text in your view. That text can be HTML, JSON amongst other things.

> I was wondering about the pros and cons of sending data to the view this way compared to retrieving the data through a web service call.

This embeds the the data as text in your view. You would need to get your view again (or a partial view) if you want that data. This is also tied to a view engine (Razor in this case). This is not a replacement for web services. See answer to item 3 below for more.

> 1) How safe is this as a method of retrieving data for an app?

Whether you use a web service or this technique, if your data is sensitive then you should use HTTPS or encrypt it or some other technique.
It is as safe as you make it.

> 2) Is there anything I can do if I wanted to pass possibly sensitive information to the view this way (like encrypt the data on the server and decrypt on the view)

See answer to item 1 above.

> 3) When in general is the best time to do something like this

I would find it very odd if you did this in your web service because then your web service will be tied to a view engine.

I have done this in the past when I wanted to include some data in my view. For example, I would include some data like this and on the browser side (using KnockoutJs) I would create a ViewModel out of this. So basically if you want some JSON to be included with your view, you can use this technique.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this would work well with an angularjs directive? I was thinking about loading data global to an angular application using this and not having to wait on any async web service calls.

Comment: I have no experience with Angularjs. All I can say is that you can render it within a script tag and I would be surprised if Angularjs could not work with it.